# spl_autoload_register vs __autoload

Tags: php

I try

```
function some_class($class) {
        require PATH.'test'.$class.'.php';
    }



function test_class($class) {
        require PATH.'some'.$class.'.php';
    }

    spl_autoload_register("test_class");
    spl_autoload_register("some_class");


    $tst = new SomeClass();
```

SomeClass class locate in "PATH/some/SomeClass.php", but spl_autoload_register call only "test_class" function and not call "some_class". But if I change functions position, then it find new SomeClass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autoload functions are called in sequential order, the first registered function is called first, the second one is called after and so on, until one of them finds the class 
(unless `$prepend` is used). If none do, a fatal error is triggered.

However, in your example, you are using `require` instead of `include`, so the first function will always fail with a fatal error if the file doesn't exist, so the second one will never be called. Even if you replace it with `include`, if both files exist, only the first registered function will be invoked.

It's a good idea to use `file_exists` or `include` when using multiple autoload functions.

You can also throw exceptions in your autoload functions, so that you can handle undefined classes gracefully instead of killing the script if a class is not found. Per example:

```
function my_autoload($class) {
     $filename = "class.{$class}.php";

     if (!file_exists($filename))
         throw new Exception("$class not found");

     include_once $filename;
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');

try {
    $a = new Foo;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Foo wasn't found
}

// continuing the script...
```

Obviously it depends on your needs, as throwing an exception will halt the execution of subsequent autoload functions.

Finally, it discouraged to use `__autoload` at all, `spl_autoload_register` providing a lot more flexibility that the former.

Comment: why is it discouraged to use autoload?

Comment: @Nick: `spl_autoload_register` is fine, `__autoload` is not, as [stated in the manual](http://php.net/__autoload). It doesn't provide much flexibility and may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Thanks..I add file_exist and all work, but why first function will always fail if I use 'require'? I use 'require' and nothing fail.

Comment: You can only define one function with a given name. Thats the problem with `__autoload()`: There can only be one (and you cannot "undefine" it)

Comment: @МехтиМустафаев: It wouldn't work because `require` fails with a *fatal error* if the file is not found. If you use `file_exists` with `require`, then it's fine.

Comment: Think twice about throwing an exception from a registered autoloader.

If you have multiple autoloaders registered, and one (or more) throws an exception before a later autoloader loads the class, stacked exceptions are thrown (and must be caught) even though the class was loaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better to just use one autoload function. Something like this:

```
function some_class($class) {
   if (file_exists(PATH.'test'.$class.'.php')) {
        include PATH.'test'.$class.'.php';
   } elseif (file_exists(PATH.'some'.$class.'.php')) {
        include PATH.'some'.$class.'.php';
   } else {
        die('class '.$class.' not found');
   }
}
spl_autoload_register("some_class");
```

Comment: I know about 1 function, I just need to test 2 autoload function :)

Answer (score 0):

spl_autoload_register-
What exactly does it mean? Let's try to understand it with the help of an example:

```
function Autoloader($className)
    {
        require_once $path.$className.'.php';
    }

    spl_autoload_register('Autoloader');

    $myObj = new MyClass();
```

Here we have just instantiated a class named as “MyClass” with out specifying include or require statements.

Is not it cool ? So how have we done it ? Let’s dig in.

Here we have registered a function named as “Autoloader” with spl_autoload_register() function. When, we instantiate “MyClass”, class name(MyClass) is passed by PHP to “spl_autoload_register()”, where registered function picks it up as a parameter. And in defination of Autoloader function, we have included the path of that class file.

This is simply great!! Just think of a situation, where you are having couple of classes and all of them are not going to be used in each case OR on each page. In such cases, spl_autoload_register() can be a real saviour for you.

You just need to instantiate and spl_autoload_register() will take care of rest.

Instead of registering a function you can also do it as follow:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

But this chunk of code works only with PHP >= 5.3.0

You can consider spl_autoload_register() as a replacement of __autoload(), which can be defined as:

__autoload() — Attempt to load undefined class

Let’s try to understand with the help of an example.

```
<?php
// we've writen this code where we need
function __autoload($classname) {
    $filename = "./". $classname .".php";
    include_once($filename);
}

// we've called a class ***
$obj = new myClass();
?>
```

But it has a demerit that you need to write this function in each of your class file.